# Sales Tax (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I need help with an activity. I keep getting the same error with I don't understand why it's there.

Here's the question, the error I'm getting and my code.

```js
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Program name: salesTaxLookup.html
        // Purpose: 
        // Author: 
        // Date last modified: October 20th 2015 

        //variables and constants 
  var salesTax  // tax 
        var purchases; // purchase 
        var BR = "<br />"; // HTML line break
        var PA = "<p />"; // HTML paragraph break
        var ES = ""; // empty string for prompt

        // welcome the user 
        document.write("Welcome to sales tax calculator!" + PA);
        salesTax = prompt("Enter your total amount of salesTax: ", ES);
        salesTax = parseFloat(salesTax);

        // calculate

        if(salesTax <=0)
   if(salesTax<=7) {
   document.write("No tax." + BR);
  }
  else if (salesTax<=21){
  document.write("1 cent tax." + BR);
  }
  else if (salesTax<=35){
  document.write("2 cent tax." + BR);
  }
  else if (salesTax<=49){
  document.write("3 cent tax." + BR); 
  }
  else if (salesTax<=64){
  document.write("4 cents tax." + BR);
  else if (salesTax<=78) {
  document.write("5 cents tax." + BR);
  }
  else if (salesTax<=92) {
  document.write("6 cents tax." + BR);
  }
  else if (salesTax<=99){
  document.write("7 cents tax." + BR)
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: The error I'm getting]
[image: Description of the activity]

Comment: You have apart from the syntax error, a logical error. You do not have any sales tax before the ifs because of  the lack of brackets belonging to `if(salesTax <=0)` - I suspect you mean `if(salesTax >=0)` - actually you can completely remove `if(salesTax <=0)`

Comment: Maybe he just wanted to explicitly point out that for negative values there's  no tax, to improve readibility ;) Jk

Answer (score 2):

You are having a syntax error at line 39, there is } missing.

Should be:

```
else if (salesTax<=64) {
    document.write("4 cents tax." + BR);
}
```

Comment: You are missing the logical error too